# How to select text between two characters in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

I have a RichTextBox that logs information about my app. Here is an example of what it may log:

```
<22:52:21:179> Starting Argo Studio
<22:52:22:731> Argo Studio has finished starting
<22:52:30:41> Time to load commands: 00:00:00.00
<22:52:30:48> Created 'App 1'
```

The text between the `<` and the `>` is the time.

**I need to change the color of the time to gray.**

Previously, I did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RichTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    int indexStart = RichTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
    int indexEnd = RichTextBox.Lines[i].Split(' ')[0].Length;
    RichTextBox.Select(indexStart, indexEnd);
    RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

However, this no longer works for me because now I have logs with multiple lines:

```
<23:0:4:320> Error-h88tzd: The source and destination are the same.
Source: 'C:\Users\user\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\...'.
Destination: 'C:\Users\user\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\....
More information: https://
```

Comment: if the log structure is constant you find on the first row the time, then skip X lines till the next line with the time and so on. if not you can use Regex to find the time part(s) in your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) to find all section of the text that match the time stamp.
Each [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) object returns the char `Index` where the match was found and the `Length` of the matched string.
This information can be used to perform a selection.

It doesn't matter whether the text is wrapped or not, since the whole text is considered.

For example:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(richTextBox.Text, @"<*\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+>*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    richTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
    richTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
    richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

Not exactly clear whether you want to select the time stamp here:

```
Time to load commands: 00:00:00.00
```

small change required if you do (e.g., set the pattern to `<*\d+:\d+:\d+[:.]\d+>*`)

If you want only the time stamps in angle brackets, then `<\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+>`

Answer (score 1):

you can skip the line if `> or <` do not exist. try this :

```
        RichTextBox.AppendText("< 22:52:21:179 > Starting Argo Studio" +
       "\r\n" + "<22:52:22:731 > Argo Studio has finished starting" +
       "\r\n" + "<22:52:30:41 > Time to load commands: 00:00:00.00" +
       "\r\n" + "< 22:52:30:48 > Created 'App 1'" +
       "\r\n" + "23:0:4:320 Error - h88tzd: The source and destination are the same." +
       "\r\n" + @"Source: 'C:\Users\user\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\...'." +
       "\r\n" + @"Destination: 'C:\Users\user\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\...." +
       "\r\n" + "More information: https:/");


        for (int i = 0; i < RichTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            int indexStart = RichTextBox.Lines[i].IndexOf("<");
            int indexEnd = RichTextBox.Lines[i].LastIndexOf(">");
            if (indexStart < 0 || indexEnd < 0)
                continue;
            int baseIndex = RichTextBox.Text.IndexOf(RichTextBox.Lines[i]);
            RichTextBox.Find(RichTextBox.Lines[i].Substring(indexStart+1, indexEnd-1));
            RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Gray;
        }
```

then the result:

[image]

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Only if the line contains `<` and `>`, then format color

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < RichTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (RichTextBox.Lines[i].Contains("<") && 
        RichTextBox.Lines[i].Contains(">"))
    {
        int indexStart = RichTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
        int indexEnd = RichTextBox.Lines[i].Split(' ')[0].Length;
        RichTextBox.Select(indexStart, indexEnd);
        RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```